# What is the null space and how to work out dimension of it?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Only need help with part iii) which i have circled what is the null space?  is is the empty space which contains no element then isn't it's dimension zero? I don't understand this question and would appreciate some help

Comment: The null space of $M$ is the same as that of its reduced row echelon form.

Comment: Are you an engineering student? Do you study at a university? Is it common to get assignments in multiple choice format?

Comment: @Panda Bear no im a maths student

Comment: Which second part ?

Comment: @Panda Bear but what exactly is the null space

Comment: The null space is another word for kernel, i.e. all of the elements which the matrix sends to the identity element, for matrices the zero vector.

Comment: You can look it up on Google. Lots of examples to practice from.

Comment: @Panda Bear sorry i don't understand whats going on

Comment: Watch this: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/null_column_space/v/introduction-to-the-null-space-of-a-matrix. He starts really from the basics.

Comment: @ whats the null space of the ref of M, how do you work that out?

Comment: I won't give you the answer. You really need to go to back to the basics, if you don't what the null space is. This assignment is already beyond that basic level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row of the reduced echelon form, locate the first element of the matrix (from the left to right) that is non-zero (mark them). Then count the number of columns that do not contain any of these marked elements. This number is the dimension of the null-space.

In your case (for the matrix circled in (D)) there is only one such column. So, the answer in (iii) is (B).

**Why this recipe works?**

The null space is the set of solutions $x$ of $Mx=0$. By replacing $M$ by its reduced echelon form $D$, the system $Dx=0$ has the same set of solutions (in particular the dimension of the set of solutions is still the same). Now, applying back substitution to the system $Dx=0$ we see that all the variables in the columns that have marked elements (as above; called pivots) can be expressed in terms of the variables (called free variables) corresponding to the columns that didn't have marked elements.

The number of free variables tells us the degrees of freedom we have to pinpoint a solution of $Dx=0$. More precisely, if we give to the free variables the value zero to all except one of them and change which free variable gets to be the non-zero one. We get for each solutions of the system $Dx=0$ that are linearly independent. Since they also generate all solutions they form a basis of the null space and their number is its dimension.